# SQL Update command not updating the database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm attempting to update the highscore of a user after he finishes the game. The highscore is not updating in the database after this code runs.

```vb
Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection
con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Project_Game\accounts1.mdb"
con2.Open()

Dim dc As OleDbCommand
dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET Highscore=@score WHERE Username=@currentUser", con2)
dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", loggedUsername)
dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score)
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
con2.Close()
```

The score variable contains the integer value of the players score and the loggedUsername variable contains the username of the logged in user as a string.

Comment: What is the value in loggedUsername?  And does that Username already exist in the db?  Look out for trailing nonprintable characters

Comment: The value in loggedUsername is the username of the logged in player (As String) and yes I am sure the values being passed in are the ones you'd expect

Comment: OleDb command uses `?` placeholder for parameters and parameters are bound by position.

Answer (score 0):

The Parameters had to be the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection
con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Project_Game\accounts1.mdb"
con2.Open()

Dim dc As OleDbCommand
dc = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET Highscore=@score WHERE Username=@currentUser", con2)
dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score)
dc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", loggedUsername)
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
con2.Close()
```